# Can we integrate, the indefinite integral $\int 2aye^{ay^2}dy$ by parts?

Tags: calculus

Can we integrate, the indefinite integral $\int 2aye^{ay^2}dy$ by parts ?

If we let, $ay^2= t$, we have $(2ay)dy=dt$ and the integral can be integrated. This process is known as integration by substitution.

Comment: why do you want to do this by parts if you can do it by a simple substitution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you're not going to like it.

Let $u=1$, $dv=2aye^{ay^2}\,dy$. Then $du=0dy$, and (by the substitution technique that you already know about) $v=e^{ay^2}$. So $$\int2aye^{ay^2}\,dy=\int u\,dv=uv-\int v\,du=e^{ay^2}-\int0dy=e^{ay^2}$$

Comment: Awww, beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it directly. Observe that

$$\left(e^{ay^2}\right)'=2aye^{ay^2}\Longrightarrow\int\,2ay\,e^{ay^2}dy=\int d\left(e^{ay^2}\right)=e^{ay^2}+K(=\text{ constant})$$

Comment: Well done, @Tharsis. Thanks